# Docker "unsupported locale setting" when running Python container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

When I try "docker run -p 8050:8050 app1" in docker I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app1.py", line 6, in <module>
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 598, in setlocale
return _setlocale(category, locale)
```

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6
USER root
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8050
ENV NAME World
CMD ["python", "app1.py"]
```

How can i set a local language in the app1.py without getting this error?
thanks in advance

PS: Already restarted docker.

Answer (score 13):

That worked for me

```
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/'        /etc/locale.gen \
 && sed -i -e 's/# pt_BR.UTF-8 UTF-8/pt_BR.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen \
 && locale-gen
```

Comment: solved it for me aswell, Django container with python:3-7-slim-buster as the base.

Comment: For other people, in my case, I needed to put `RUN apt-get update` before.